# Evaluate XACML 3.0 combining algorithms

Tags: authorization, access-control, policy, xacml, abac

I am studying XACML 3.0 access control and I found this complex question about Evaluate XACML 3.0 combining algorithms. I can solve a simple exercise but this one hard for me and I need some help with it

policy p1:
- op: permit-overrides

- rule: permit if match all: group = staff, resource = file1
- rule: permit if match all: group = student, resource = file2
- rule: deny if match: any

policy p2:

- op: deny-overrides
- rule: deny if match all: time [MBP] = night
- rule: permit if match all: time [MBP] = day

policy p3:

- op: deny-overrides
- policy: p1
- policy: p2

Evaluate for each policy the following requests q1, q2 and q3:

- q1 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1), (time, day)}
- q2 = {(group, student), (resource, file2), (time, night)}
- q3 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Evaluation Results using P1 only

- q1 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1), (time, day)}

  - **Response:** Permit. The first rule in P1 kicks in and the combining algorithm makes the process stop there. The time of day has no impact on the decision making.
- q2 = {(group, student), (resource, file2), (time, night)}

  - **Response:** Permit. The second rule in P1 kicks in and the combining algorithm makes the process stop there. The time of day, again, has no impact on the decision making.
- q3 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1)}

  - **Response:** Permit. This is essentially the same as q1.

## Evaluation Results using P2 only

- q1 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1), (time, day)}

  - **Response:** Permit because all access is permitted in day time. Rule 1 inside P2 does not apply. Rule 2 grants access.
- q2 = {(group, student), (resource, file2), (time, night)}

  - **Response:** Deny because all access is denied at nighttime. Rule 1 inside P2 applies. The combining algorithm is such that the processing stops after rule 1.
- q3 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1)}

  - **Response:** Not applicable. The two rules only trigger if the time of day has been specified, which isn't the case in this request. Therefore the evaluation ends in NotApplicable.

## Evaluation Results using P3 (a combination of P1 and P2)

- q1 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1), (time, day)}

  - **Response:** Access is permitted because staff is allowed to view file1 in daytime.
- q2 = {(group, student), (resource, file2), (time, night)}

  - **Response:**  Access is denied regardless of what the student is trying to view. In this case, the nighttime policy trumps all other policies because of the over-arching combining algorithm (deny-overrides) in P3.
- q3 = {(group, staff), (resource, file1)}

  - **Response:** Access is permitted because staff is allowed to view file1 and no time has been specified.

## Notes

The policy that grants access during daytime is not necessary. As a matter of fact, it might even open up access you would not want to have. For instance, given the current policy, a student can edit their own exam grades so long as it's daytime.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot to understand how the policies working.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is detailed and largely correct except for two cases involving a Rule's Target missing an attribute for which MustBePresent is set to true.

Only those cases will be addressed here in this answer.

## policy p2 - request q3

- rule: deny if match all: time [MBP] = night -> Indeterminate{D} because of missing time attribute and MustBePresent = true and the rule effect is Deny
- rule: permit if match all: time [MBP] = day -> Indeterminate{P} because of the similar reason
- op:denyOverrides -> Indeterminate{DP}

The evaluation result is Indeterminate{DP}

## policyset p3 - request q3:

- policy p1

  - rule: permit if match all: group = staff, resource = file1 -> Permit
  - op:permitOverrides -> Permit regardless of the outcome of any other rules
- policy p2 -> Indeterminate{DP} as explained in the previous case
- op:denyOverrides -> Indeterminate{DP}

The evaluation result is Indeterminate{DP}

## References

The XACML 3.0 specification contain all the details necessary for your understanding

- For the attribute retrieval and MustBePresent flag refer to [section 7.3.5](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047178)
- For the combining algorithms refer to [Appendix C](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047268)

Comment: Can I change P1 or/and P2 to make q3 evaluates to Permit ?

Comment: In the case of p2 to avoid getting Indeterminate with q3 you can use the rule combining algorithm permit-unless-deny. For p3-q3 to evaluate to permit there are more options since p1 already evaluates to a permit. For instance any policy combining algorithm that prioritize permit such as permit-overrides or deny-unless-permit will do.